# how a django reusable apps can initialize itself?

Tags: python, django, reusability, django-tinymce

I'm creating a django app as a python package , almost similar to [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce)
interesting point about django-tinymce is that every time I restart my web server , for example I run :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

somehow automatically  a [settings.py](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/blob/master/tinymce/settings.py) file inside django-tinymce start running.
how is this possible ?
I just add tinymce in the INSTALLED_APPS and nothing else but the code inside `python2.7/site-packages/tinymce/settings.py` starts running and do a few initialization operations every time I restart my web server or run any manage.py command.

Comment: what kind of initialization operations are you talking about?

Comment: @Ales initialization for adding a directory path to STATICFILES_DIRS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As django 1.7 each app can contain an app.py file to do any initialization it needs to do.
Imagine we have a app called profile.In your app directory create an apps.py like this :

```
#apps.py 
from django.apps import AppConfig 
class ProfileConfig(AppConfig):
     name = "profiles"
     verbose_name = 'User Profiles'
     def ready(self):
         #do what ever you want
```

One more step to complete this behavior is to specify `default_app_config`
Which should happened in **init**.py of your app :

```
# profile/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'profile.apps.ProfileConfig'
```

This behavior can be used in many usecases including : changing project settings,registering signal handlers

More details can be found in [Django 1.7 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor) and [Django docs:Applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Such initialisation code is often put in the models.py which is run by Django at start or restart.
In this example app it is just a matter of imports run - models.py imports widgets and widgets import settings.